# Spring service returns empty result if the real result is to large

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, controller

I am working on a Spring service that gets data from DB and returns a JSON with a list of objects.
This service returns ALL records that we have in a specific table. In total about 10,000 records more or less.

The method of obtaining data is fast (Using Threads), but when the service returns the results of the request it is when it is slow.

Also when the size of the json exceeds 700 records we get an empty result. Each object in the list has about 70 fields.

Does anyone know any method so that Spring does not take so long to return the results?

Is there a response size limit for a Spring service?

Here you have the code

```
    public String getData(final Pageable pageable) throws Exception {
        
        final int numberOfThreads = 10;

        final StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("{" + "\"content\": [");

        // Here we are obtaining all the data in diferents treads and appending in variable String 
         strContent 
        
        String strContent = getDataByThreads(numberOfThreads);
        // Here strContent contains 10.000 or more objects in JSON format


        logger.info(" -------------- END OF {} THREADS  ----------------- ", numberOfThreads);

        final long totalPages = (totalCount / fetchSize) + 1;
        final boolean last = Math.ceil(totalPages) == pageable.getPageNumber();
        final boolean first = pageable.getPageNumber() == 0;

        // Mounting the response JSON
        str.append(strContent);
        str.append("],");
        str.append("\"last\": " + last + ",");
        str.append("\"totalElements\": " + totalCount + ",");
        str.append("\"totalPages\": " + totalPages + ",");
        str.append("\"first\": " + first + ",");
        str.append("\"numberOfElements\": " + fetchSize + ",");
        str.append("\"size\": " + fetchSize + ",");
        str.append("\"number\": " + pageable.getPageNumber());
        str.append("}");

        // Here is where Spring takes a long time...
        return str.toString();
    }
```

As you can see, we return a JSON in String format because the objects have dynamic fields and are not fixed.

Thank you.

Comment: The idea behind a `Pageable` request is to return the contents for a single page (how you do that depends on several things). Returning *all* the data for backend paging is wrong by design.